# Angular 7 children components style is not working

Tags: css, mime-types, styling, angular-components, angular7

When I reload my angular children component the page gets white and I'm getting an error

> Refused to apply style from '[URL]' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

So as long as I route through my page by clicking buttons that change my `routerLink` everything works.

---

#### Update

I have this error only in `production mode` so when I use `ng serve` I can reload my page and I don't get any errors and in the `Developer Tools` I also see all files in the `Source tab`, which is not the case when I inspect the page in `production mode`

---

I've already

- changed

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.9eca5df2f679ed98933c.css">
  ```

  to

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.9eca5df2f679ed98933c.css">
  ```
- build my project with `vendorChunk=true` in my `angular.json`
- commented every related html and css out
- removed any comments in my stylesheets
- set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on both, parent and child
- checked `<base href="/">` in my `index.html` `<head> tag` and changed it to `<base href="./">` because otherwise nothing works

---

I guess there is no stylesheet at `[URL]` but I don't know why and how I can specify the URL to the related stylesheet, because `styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']` in the `@Component`-Decorator does obviously not work when I build my project in `production mode` (--prod).

By the way I don't use any external stylesheets, as this may be the cause of my error I found out when I searched for this problem.

This error only occurs on children components with the following routes:

```
/<parent>/:id/<child>
```

to which a navigate by

```
this.router.navigate(['../server/' + guild.id + "/dashboard"], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

in every browser

---

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: I've mentioned that I'm not using any library and I've already removed any comments in my stylesheets

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/">` in your HTML `<head>` (from https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170#issuecomment-386117678)

Comment: when I use `<base href="/">` nothing works so I changed it to `<base href="./">` and this works fine as long as I'm not viewing a child component

Comment: Did you try adding it to the `styles` attribute in angular.json and removing the `<link>` tag from the html?
`"styles": ["src/styles.scss"],`

Comment: this is the case by default (for me). The `<link>` tag is created when I build the project in `production mode` (--prod) and `"styles": ["src/styles.css"]` is presented in the `angular.json`

Comment: Could you try setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on the child component?

Comment: I tried this as well and it didn't work. And this won't be a good solution by the way, because it will make the styling globally and this is not what I want

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325#issuecomment-402050207

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've a similar error but not the exact same. In my case the MIME type is not supported and in the discussion you've sent the MIME type is not executable

Comment: Is this the issue with every browser?

Comment: Yes it is in every browser

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the path of your CSS.

Comment: I think so. But I don't know how to specify the path correctly in angular or if it is already correct and I changed something else so the browser can't find it. But I mentioned this in my post

Comment: Hopefully you've resolved this by now, but my two cents... Maybe it's getting a 'text/html' MIME type because a 404 HTML response page is being returned instead of the stylesheet. If so, that seems to indicate a path issue, possibly in the angular.json config.